# Controls not working in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm working on a project in which, video will be played when a button is clicked. MPMoviePlayer worked fine before I use this button action. But after implementing that, Video plays fine but the player doesn't recognise touch and it doesn't even shows playback time. Only showing like this ( - - ).

I'm working on this code:

```
-(void) sceneBegins:(id)sender
{
   ....
theMoviePlayer = [MPMoviePlayerController new];

    [theMoviePlayer setContentURL:movieURL];

    theMoviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

    theMoviePlayer.backgroundView.hidden = YES;

    [theMoviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

    theMoviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

    [theMoviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    [theMoviePlayer.view setFrame:View.bounds];
 [theMoviePlayer.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    theMoviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

 [View addSubview:theMoviePlayer.view];
 theMoviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
  [theMoviePlayer play];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sceneChange:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMoviePlayer];

....
}
```

Also it doesn't enters in to the stop notification method when the video stops playing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code :-

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragEnded:withEvent: )
    forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside |
    UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```